# How to use the Hijri calendar in my GWT application? 

Tags: java, gwt

I am working on Internationalization. I wanted to include Hijri Calendar for my application.  Any idea how to go about it?. I am using gwt 2.4.0 and trying this out using datebox widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using the third party library, I would suggest checking out [GWT-time](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-time/).

> GWT-time provides true date and time manipulations for both GWT and
>   non-GWT projects in the style of Joda-time.

It has [IslamicChronology](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-time/source/browse/gwt-time/trunk/src/org/gwttime/time/chrono/IslamicChronology.java?r=5)  class that implements the Islamic, or Hijri, calendar system using arithmetic rules.

**Updated:**
Actually GWT-time uses [Joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) style, and see [Using Islamic chronology in Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_islamic.html)

```
DateTime dtISO = new DateTime(2004, 5, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0);

DateTime dtIslamic = dtISO.withChronology(IslamicChronology.getInstance());

Window.alert(dtIslamic.toString());
```

Don't forget to inherit GWT-time in your *.gwt.xml

```
 <inherits name="org.gwttime.Time"/>
```